# Configure networking on debian live standard iso using usb tethering

Tags: debian, networking, live-usb

I just downloaded Debian standard live iso from [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/). I have an Android device capable of usb tethering. I live booted from the debian live iso and got into login tty and connected my phone and turned on usb tethering and mobile data, and ran `apt update` as sudo su from terminal. I got error, could not establish connection. I ran `systemctl status NetworkMamager` it said, no service with that name could be found. Then I ran `/etc/init.d/networking start`. But still couldn't get online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**note: This desktop does not have a wifi module, and I don't happen to have an ethernet cable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the name of the USB interface through `ip a` command (e,g: `usb0`).

Set the interface up:

```
sudo ip link set usb0 up
```

Then run :

`sudo dhclient usb0`.

Debian: [Android_Tethering](https://wiki.debian.org/Android_Tethering)

Comment: Yep worked!!! I didn't even have to set up ip link, I just ran `ip a` and got the interface name **enp2s029f7u1** and did `dhclient enp2s029f7u1` and I was able to ping debian.org. Thanks (: Have a nice day (: